# how does the binary left shift is behaving after 30 shift in c++?

Tags: c++, binary, bit-shift

in C++ int is of 4 bytes that means that int memory it can store 32 bits, then how come

```
int i = 1;
i = i<<32;
cout<<i<<endl;
```

gives me the following error:-

```
main.cpp:7:5: warning: shift count >= width of type
      [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  i <<= 32;
```

whereas

```
  int i = 1;
    i = i<<31;
    cout<<i<<endl;
```

gives me

```
./main
-2147483648
```

and

```
  int i = 1;
    i = i<<30;
    cout<<i<<endl;
```

gives me

```
./main
1073741824
```

what is happening?

Comment: What's unclear about "shift count >= width of type"? Shift count = 32; width of type = 32; hence shift count >= width of type is true.

Comment: And your second snippet moves `1` into what is the "sign bit" on **almost all** systems: if this is set, the number is negative.

Comment: If you're ever confused, always remember, the most significant bit in a signed `int` has place value `-2^31`. For example, consider if all bit are set. Then total value equals `-2^31 + (2^30 + 2^29 + ... + 2^1 + 2^0) = -2^31 + (2^31-1) = -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's represent a number in a binary format and see what a left shift does.

```
for example

    if i = 5        // binary 101
    i<<1 becomes 10 // binary 1010
    i<<2 becomes 20 // binary 10100

and so on
```

Similarly

```
    if i = 1          // binary 1
    i<<1 becomes 2    // binary 10
    i<<2 becomes 4    // binary 100
    i<<n becomes 2^n  // binary 1000...n times
    i<<30 becomes 2^30 // binary 1000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you observe 2^n will require n+1 bits to store, which explains your first error. 2^32 will need 33 bits and std int being 32 bit, you get an overflow error.

Now note that 2^30 occupies 31 bits which are the number of bits allocated to represent the value of int since the 32nd bit is a sign bit (to distinguish between negative and positive numbers).

So, when you do i<<31, the highest order 1 overwrites the sign bit and we get a negative value.

Negative numbers in c++ represented using 2s complement. 2s complement of 2^31 for a 32 bit value is -2147483648 which is what you see.

Now i<<30 when i==1 is just 2^30 or 1073741824